# Link with Runtime Package in Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi Tokyo and I would like to build my `App.exe` with some run-time packages, so I have setup my project's options as shown below

[image]

I manually typed into the run-time packages list as shown below

[image]

While building the project I got error message that those rtl250, vcl250 could not be found

[image]

When trying to add those packages using browse button, Delphi asked me to find those packages using `.dcp` extention not `.bpl`, which I have no ideas where to find those files

[image]

Please guide me how to fix this

Comment: Use only rtf, vcl without the number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names you must specify there are the names of the .dcp files. These do not contain the version numbers. Use:

```
rtl, vcl
```

...rather than:

```
rtl250, vcl250
```

...and it will work.

This is actually a feature (introduced many years ago), so you don't have to change those names when you upgrade to a new Delphi version.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this http://i.cubeupload.com/FLNcnY.png, and re-built the project without further errors.

My understanding is that specifying some run-time packages e.g. `rtl`, `vcl` means to bundle those run-times into the `.exe` so I don't need to deploy those run-times separately.

If my understanding is wrong, what's different between specifying those run-times and leave it empty as http://i.cubeupload.com/rBSMbv.png

Comment: @Artisan: Your understanding is incorrect. Building with runtime packages stops the contents of those packages from being bundled into your .exe, so you must distribute those package libraries along with your .exe. If you want them linked (bundled) into your .exe, you do *not* want to build with runtime packages..